# Scala self-type and generic class

Tags: scala, generics, types, self-type

```
abstract class Bar[M] {
  def print(t: M): Unit = {
    println(s"Bar: ${t.getClass()}")
  }
}

trait Foo[M] {
  this: Bar[M] =>
  def print2(t: M): Unit = {
    println(s"Foo: ${t.getClass()}")
  }
}

object ConcreteBar extends Bar[Int] with Foo[Int] {}
object ConcreteFooBar extends Bar[Int] with Foo[Int] {}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    ConcreteBar.print(1)
    ConcreteFooBar.print2(1)
  }
```

In the example above, is there a way so that we don't have to repeat the type in the self-typed "bar" trait?
Therefore we could declare ConcreteFooBar like this:

```
object ConcreteFooBar extends Bar[Int] with Foo {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an abstract type instead of a type parameter for `Foo`, like this:

```
abstract class Bar[M] {
  type Base = M
  def print(t: M): Unit = {
    println(s"Bar: ${t.getClass()}")
  }
}

trait Foo {
  type Base
  def print2(t: Base): Unit = {
    println(s"Foo: ${t.getClass()}")
  }
}
```