# Inference of type parameters on mixins

Tags: scala

Let's say I have some trait:

```
trait A[T] { def foo: T }
```

A class which extends it:

```
class B[T](t: T) extends A[T] { def foo = t }
```

And a subtrait of the parent trait:

```
trait C[T] extends A[T]
```

I want to mix C in with B.

```
val foo = new B("foo") with C[String]
```

This works fine, but I'd rather not need to specify the type parameter again, since B is already of type A[String]. However, I recognize Scala doesn't support the following:

```
val foo = new B("foo") with C
```

My question is where there's some other mechanism in the type system to support not having to specify the type parameters when C is mixed in. What I was thinking of was something as follows:

```
trait C {
  self: A[T] => ...
}
```

One would think this kind of thing would fix what C could be mixed into. However, it isn't valid Scala. Something like:

```
trait C {
  type T
  self: A[T] =>
}
```

does not work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala self-type and generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554414/scala-self-type-and-generic-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an abstract type:

```
  trait A {
    type AT
    def foo: AT
  }

  class B[T](t: T) extends A {
    type AT = T 
    def foo = t
  }

  trait C extends A

  val foo = new B("foo") with C
```

The definition is a bit more verbose, but your requirement of not having to type `T` again is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me everything. And finally I have a concrete example where you'd use abstract types over type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
scala> trait C {
     |   self: A[_] => 
     | }
defined trait C

scala> val foo = new B("foo") with C
foo: B[String] with C = $anon$1@f2df380

scala> foo.foo
res16: String = foo
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Thank you. The downside there is it sort of erases your ability to refer to the type. I should have made my example more concrete. Let's say C has the form:   trait C[T] extends A[T] { def take(t: T) = Unit }. Is there any way to adapt this method to be able to define such a take method?